# D3.js Multiple GeoJSON objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I am trying to transition between two GeoJSON objects, but have been unable to find any information on how to include more than one GeoJSON file. I am happy with the final transformation, but cannot find anything on multiple GeoJSON files.

I can currently plot one map like so:

```
d3.json("goldatt2.json", function (data) {

    var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.equirectangular());

    var areas = group.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
```

How would I change this so that two GeoJSON files are called and can be transformed?

I found this example, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153 but in this example there is only GeoJSON object that is then transformed to a circle.

Comment: For the second GeoJSON, the pattern is almost the same, except that need to handle the update selection as well. That is, transform the paths from the first into the second one. As far as loading the GeoJSON is concerned, you would do exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the Data is separate task with respect to transforming it.

So you could, in theory, have multiple ajax calls to fetch the data you need **before** you decide to do whatever with that data.

Mike Bostock has a [Queue](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) implementation for this purpose.
If you are using JQuery with D3, you could look into [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) an example of which is posted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/serendipity/dryLB/).

Once you have the data-sets that you need, you can now decide how you want to transform the data or provide transitions between them.

Pseudo-code:

```
var files = ["file1.json", "file2.json"];

//Fetch Data for both files and create a data set object of this format
var dataset = {
    "file1.json": {/*geojson data for file1*/},
    "file2.json": {/*geojson data for file2*/}
}

for(var item in dataset) {
    var data = dataset[item];
    //Do whatever transformation you need
}
```